# Hibernate criteria - single object fetched

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm working on a Grails project using Hibernate (GORM). I have the following Domain Models:

```
ClientContact {
   static hasMany = [owners: Person]
   static belongsTo = [Person]
}

Person {
   static hasMany = [clientContacts: ClientContact]
}
```

When I try to retrieve all the `ClientContacts` with a specific owner (`Person`), I'm running into some funny issues.  I'm using the following query criteria:

```
def query = {
   owners {
      eq("id", Long.parseLong(params.ownerId))
   }
}
def criteria = ClientContact.createCriteria()
def results = criteria.list(params, query)
```

The problem is when I iterate through each of my `ClientContacts` in the results, they only have **the one owner** - when in fact, most have many other owners.  What gives?  I know hibernate/GORM uses lazy fetching, but I thought it would fetch all of the other owners on a `ClientContact` when I tried to access them.

Any thoughts?  I would like to continue using the *list()* function since it provides some nice paging features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this thread is very old, but I just encountered exactly the same problem today and the solution seems to be usage of aliases, so instead:

```
def query = {
        owners {
                eq("id", Long.parseLong(params.ownerId))
        }
}
```

one can try:

```
def query = {
        createAlias("owners", "o")
        eq("o.id", Long.parseLong(params.ownerId))
}
```

The first query creates left outer joins and the second creates inner joins. Please see this link for more detailed description: http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2009/06/querying-by-association-redux.html

Answer (score 0):

Two quick observations:

1. The [Grails Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.2.1.3 Many-to-many) says that a **many-to-many** association has to be manually coded, the default scaffolding won't do it.
2. You may need to use the `eqId()` criterion - see [createCriteria](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)

Comment: I've added all the appropriate methods to support the many-to-many associations. I know this because I can add ClientContacts with owners. The problem is in the retrieval -as highlighted above.

I tried the eqId() search criteria but it ends up returning the exact opposite ClientContacts.  I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

id and version are special properties of all GORM classes.  You don't need to specify them in the class declaration, and you can't use the standard criterion with them.

You definitely need to use the eqID criterion

```
   def query = {
          owners {
                eqId(Long.parseLong(params.ownerId))
          }
   }
   def criteria = ClientContact.createCriteria()
   def results = criteria.list(params, query)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I use your above code... I get an error that "No signature of method: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.eqId() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Long) values: {123}".

When I use idEq, as seen here: http://grails.org/Hibernate+Criteria+Builder, I get an empty list.